# Selecting surface constraint using ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-pro

I created a model using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro to make a LAS ground only layer from LAS files. I first created LAS dataset using LAS files and then used make las dataset layer option. I am able to apply surface constraint to the main LAS dataset but the issue is that surface constraint is not applied in final LAS layer.

I have attached screenshot of my model and the issue faced.

The short version of my problem is The model is not able to select surface constraint automatically.

[image: LAS Model] [image: Surface constraint]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to forward (re-use) the parameter from the **Create LAS Dataset** step again in the **Make Dataset Layer** step. *R-click >> Create Variable >> From parameter >> Surface Constraints*.

[image: screenshot of parameters in context menu]